# How to resize the uploaded image to specific width in carrierwave gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, crop

I am uploading an image to my rails app using `carrierwave`.

I wish to have the `max-width` fixed to a specific size and `height` according to the `width`.

When I am doing it like this

```
version :medium do
   resize_to_limit(600,0)
end
```

Then the image is not coming up.

Also, What's the difference between `resize_to_limit` and `resize_to_fit`

Please guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are content with having only one version, then you can just add this to your uploader:

```
include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
process resize_to_fill: [600, 0]
```

Here is the [documentation for resize_to_limit](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/carrierwave/CarrierWave/MiniMagick#resize_to_limit-instance_method/CarrierWave%2FMiniMagick%3Aresize_to_limit):

> Resize the image to fit within the specified dimensions while retaining the original aspect ratio. Will only resize the image if it is larger than the specified dimensions. The resulting image may be shorter or narrower than specified in the smaller dimension but will not be larger than the specified values.

Here's for [resize_to_fit](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/carrierwave/CarrierWave/MiniMagick#resize_to_fit-instance_method):

> Resize the image to fit within the specified dimensions while retaining the original aspect ratio. The image may be shorter or narrower than specified in the smaller dimension but will not be larger than the specified values.

And here for [resize_to_fill](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/carrierwave/CarrierWave/MiniMagick#resize_to_fill-instance_method):

> Resize the image to fit within the specified dimensions while retaining the aspect ratio of the original image. If necessary, crop the image in the larger dimension.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recreate new version of image uploader like :-

```
version :medium do
    process :resize_to_fill => [600,0]
end
```

Then recreate them :-

```
User.all.each do |user|
    user.avatar.recreate_versions!
end
```

Comment: include CarrierWave::Uploader::Versions
include CarrierWave::Uploader::Cache
include CarrierWave::Storage